# Give domain users administrator account or access to software center

Tags: permissions, policykit

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a couple of machines. The domain is running Windows.
I have managed to add machines in domain with likewise-open and give sudo access to domain groups.

Problem is that domain user are "Standard" users and when trying to use Ubuntu software center or synaptic packet manager their are asked for the administrators account password.

The domain user have sudo access but the PC's will be used for Office work and the people using them are not familiar with terminal and command lines. And the software center has pictures and description of the app making it easy to choose the right ones.

I am looking for a way to promote all existing and future accounts that belong to a group in the domain to be administrator level accounts or for a way to give all users in a group access to software center and maybe all other applications that require authentication from administrator account.

When a standard user starts synaptic or software center they are asked for administrator password and no manual login for example is available.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose my answer here [Software Center prompts password of another user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385520/software-center-prompts-password-of-another-user) may help you?

You will need assign your domain users a group to which you want to grant these admin rights and then add that group to `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf`.