# Software Center prompts password of another user

Tags: 13.10, software-center, sudo, authentication, policykit

I have a krb5-ldap user in an "administrators" which is added to sudoers list as follows:

```
%administrators ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Now that works fine for all sudo operations.

But when that user wants to install something in the Ubuntu Software Center, he gets prompted for the password of a local "admin" user.

I have no idea why it would behave that way. How can I fix this?

### Update

Also tried to add these users to the sudo groups with pam-groups in `/etc/security/group.conf`:

```
*;*;%administrators;Al0000-2400;sudo
```

The `sudo` group now shows up correctly in `groups`, however the software center still asks for the password for another, local user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add `adminstrators` to the policy kit in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf`:

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin;unix-group:administrators
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add them to sudo group and not administrator group. Previously there is admin group but its changed to sudo group and If you made it for sudo group then it wont ask password any longer.

[For more information and better understanding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Remove_Password_Prompt_For_sudo)

Comment: The groups are defined on the LDAP server. I can't really change that. Unless there is a way to say that all adminstrators are also in the sudo group locally.

Comment: I've added the group "sudo" to the users through pam_groups: `*;*;%administrators;Al0000-2400;sudo` so that the groups now show as: `users sudo administrators`. But the software center still wants the password for a local user. So your solution doesn't seem to work.